# ¿Cómo puedo insertar manualmente una operacion detro de un TextField de JavaFX?

Tags: java, operador

Es decir, hacer algo como esto y que el resultado sea **11**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**NOTA:** Tomando en cuenta que a la operación que haga siempre se le van a sumar 3 por que así lo tengo programado; así que en realidad lo que quiero hacer el 4+4 que es igual a 8, más los 3 que siempre serán sumados por default, lo que me daría **11**.

Pero al hacerlo no reconoce más que el primer número que inserto y no hace la operacion dentro del TextField (hace 4+3 por eso da como resultado 7). ¿Cómo puedo hacer que dentro del mismo TextField pueda hacer la operación y despues el resultado de esa operación sumarlo siempre + 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El componente TextField no fue diseñado para resolver operaciones matematicas, sino para mostrar informacion en los formatos aceptado por el mismo. Para hacer lo que tienes pensado, debes crear los algoritmos necesarios para extraer este String y convertirlo en la operacion que deseas realizar,

Ejm: Algoritmo solo para sumar a partir de un texto

```
public String operacionSUMA(String texto){ 
    String numeros[] = texto.split("\\+");

    int calculo = 0;

    for(String elemento : numeros){
        try {
            calculo += Integer.parseInt(elemento.trim());
            System.out.println("sumando: "+elemento.trim());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("No se puede realizar la operacion debibo a que: "+elemento+" no es un numero valido.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "No valido";
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(calculo);
}
```

y esta es la operacion luego de instanciarla

```
System.out.println("resultado: "+pm.operacionSUMA("3 + 7+4"));
```

Resultados

- sumando: 3
- sumando: 7
- sumando: 4
- resultado: 14